# Is $S(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ dense in $L^{1}_{\textrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, schwartz-space

Let $S(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ denote the class of Schwartz functions in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Is it true that $S(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is dense in $L^{1}_{\textrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, the locally integrable functions, in some norm?

Comment: I would guess that given a vector space $V$ and a subspace $W$ of the same algebraic dimension, there is a norm on $V$ such that $W$ is dense...